# Broken caching of images loaded from homemade webserver

Tags: http, caching, webserver, etag

A while ago I wrote a webserver which I'm using on a site of mine.

When I navigate to another page in Chrome while the images from this homemade webserver are still loading, they stay cached as only half-loaded.

Is this a known bug in Chrome, or an issue with my implementation of the HTTP protocol?

My webserver uses E-Tags for caching.

Comment: Sounds like you need to upgrade to a real web server.

Answer (score 0):

[**First Rule of Programming: It's your fault**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

> Start with your code, and investigate
>   further and further outward until you
>   have definitive evidence of where the
>   problem lies.

You need to apply this rule here. What are the chances that Chrome, when communicating with Apache, is likely to exhibit this kind of bug deep into it's 6 (at least) major iteration?

I would put a traffic analyser onto your server and view the exchanges carefully. Next I would compare them with those from a well-established web server like Apache and note any differences.